Getting all MDX element from a folder with React and Next
I'm new to react and next and I'm trying to make a blog.
My project is setup like this :
app/
  blog/
    page.tsx

content/
  blog/
    test.mdx

I'm trying to get all the details at the top of a mdx file that look like this
---
title: test
description: test mais en description
date: 2024-04-15
published: true
---

Heres a part of the page.tsx :
import { posts } from "#site/content";
import { PostItem } from "@/components/post-item";

export default async function BlogPage() {
 const displayPosts = posts;

The problem is the first import where I get this error:
Cannot find module '#site/content' or its corresponding type declarations.

I saw multiple people doing this and I wonder why it doesnt work for me. If you know why please help me :,)
